# Stuck on solving differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I have tried to solve :

> $$\begin{array}{l} A\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{{dr}}\left(
>  {r\frac{{du}}{{dr}}} \right) =  - B + N{k^2}\frac{{{I_0}\left( {kr}
>  \right)}}{{{I_0}\left( {ka} \right)}}\\ BC:\\ u(r) = a\\
> \frac{{du}}{{dr}} = 0\,\,\,at\,\,\,\,r = 0 \end{array}$$

with

```
DSolve[A (1/r) D[r  D[u[r], r], r] == -B +  N  k^2  (BesselI[0, k r]/ BesselI[0, a r]), u'[0] == 0, u[a] == 0, u[r], r]
```

but I didn't have any solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your typo's to match your latex and we get a solution no problem.

```
ode = (A*D[r*D[u[r], r], r])/r == -B + (n*k^2*BesselI[0, k*r])/BesselI[0, k*a]

bc1 = u'[0] == 0
bc2 = u[a] == 0

DSolve[{ode, bc1, bc2}, u[r], r] // Flatten

{u[r] -> (
  a^2 B BesselI[0, a k] - 4 n BesselI[0, Sqrt[a^2 k^2]] - 
   B r^2 BesselI[0, a k] + 4 n BesselI[0, Sqrt[k^2 r^2]])/(
  4 A BesselI[0, a k])
```

Comment: first I thank you so much, second could you tell me where is my typo's? with many thanks

Comment: You have `BesselI[0,a r]` instead of `BesselI[0,k a]` in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are better with correct syntax. You missed a pair of braces (`{ }`) around the equations. Moreover, `N` is a built-in symbol, so I replaced it with `n`. This is how the corrected code looks like:

```
DSolve[{
  A (1/r) D[r D[u[r], r], r] == -B + n k^2 (BesselI[0, k r]/BesselI[0, a r]),
  u'[0] == 0,
  u[a] == 0
  },
 u[r],
 r
 ]
```

However, it takes forwever to evaluate. This tells me that it is quite likely that no closed-form solution can be derived (under the given information). If you are interested only in a solution for concrete values of `B`, `k`, `n`, and `a`, you should first assign these values and use the numerical solver `NDSolve` instead. Parameter studies can be performed with `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: thanks for reply, unfortunately I need analytical solution only

Comment: `BesselI[0, a r]` should be BesselI[0, k a]`.